# updateExistingPivot() not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to update a pivot table like this:

```
public function updatePermission($id, $permissionId)
{
    $permissionValue = Input::get('value');
    $user = User::find($id);

    $perms = ['value' => $permissionValue];
    $user->permissions()->updateExistingPivot($permissionId, $perms);
}
```

This pivot has been previously created with:

```
public function attachPermission($id)
{
    $permissionId = Input::get('id');
    $permissionValue = Input::get('value');
    $user = User::find($id);

    if (!$user->permissions->contains($permissionId)) {

        $user->attachPermissionById($permissionId);
        $perms = ['value' => $permissionValue];
        $user->permissions()->updateExistingPivot($permissionId, $perms);

    } else {

        return Response::json(array('error' => 'Permission ' . $permissionId . ' is alreay set for user ' . $user->id));

    }

    return Response::json(array('role' => User::with(['roles.permissions', 'permissions', 'students'])->find($user->id)));
}
```

When the updatePermission() method is hit, it passes fine, but it doesn't update the pivot table with the new value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you ever get updateExistingPivot to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't tell you why it doesn't work, but I suggest you do this:

```
public function attachPermission($id)
{
    $permissionId = Input::get('id');
    $value = Input::get('value');
    $user = User::find($id);

    $sync = $user->permissions()->sync([$permissionId => compact('value')], false);

    return (in_array($permissionId, $sync['updated']))
       ? Response::json(...) // permission updated
       : Response::json(...); // permission added
}
```

It will add or update new permission for you.