# UpdateExistingPivot method doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update a value in a pivot table. This is my method :

```
public function updateStatus(Event $event)
{
    $this->authorize('updateStatus', $event);

    $newStatus = Input::get('status');
    $actualPivot = $event->guests()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->pivot;

    $id = $actualPivot['id'];
    $status = $actualPivot['status'];

    if ($newStatus != $status)
    {
        dd($event->guests()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['status' => $newStatus]));
    }

    return back();
}
```

I've checked with HeidiSQL, the row isn't updated how it should be. I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407596/updateexistingpivot-not-working), but it doesn't update the row, it creates a new one. There is the `dd()` with this method:

```
array:3 [▼
  "attached" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 1
  ]
  "detached" => []
  "updated" => []
]
```

This is my `guests()` relation defined in the `Event` model:

```
public function guests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                ->using('App\Invitation')
                ->withPivot('id', 'status')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I don't know why the `updateExistingPivot()` method doesn't work. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `guest_id` or whatever is the name for your foreign key of `App\Invitation` instead of your pivot id in order to update the existing record, otherwise you have not a relation for the current event that matches your pivot id.

```
$id = $actualPivot['guest_id']; // change guest_id for your foreig key name of \App\Invitation
$status = $actualPivot['status'];
if ($newStatus != $status)
{
    dd($event->guests()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['status' => $newStatus]));
}
```